# Getting two varaibles from command output in one execution run

Tags: linux, bash

I'm building a script in bash for use on Linux, and I use the output of a executable to fill parameters:

```
version=$("${path_exec}" -version | awk '{if($1=="kernel" && $2=="release") print $3}')
patch=$("${path_exec}" -version | awk '{if($1=="patch" && $2=="number") print $3}')
```

This will run the executable defined in "path_exec" twice, which is time consuming. Is there a way to assign the version and path variable with a value using only one execution of "path_exec"?

An example of what I've tried to tackle this is shown below, but I don't think this will do what I want:

```
${path_hostexec} -version | awk '{if($1=="kernel" && $2=="release") {version_agent = $3;} else if($1=="patch" && $2=="number") {patch_agent = $3;}}'
```

Comment: Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41236640/1765658)! Search about `Reading more than one variable`!

Comment: Could you post output sample of `${path_exec}` , without `awkl` !?

Comment: Could you please check my solution once if that helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following. Since I didn't have output of `path_exec` command so couldn't test it.

```
myarr=($("${path_exec}" -version | awk '{if($1=="kernel" && $2=="release");val=$3} {if($1=="patch" && $2=="number") print val,$3}'))
#Now get every element in the array
for i in "${myarr[@]}"
do
  echo $i
done
```

***What I have done is:***

- Merged your both `awk` programs into one to make it run on a single time.
- Now creating an array by output of `awk` command output(which should be `val1  val2` as an example format)
- Once an array created then we could get its all values by `for` loop or you could get its specific value by mentioning its index eg--> `myarr[1]` to print 2nd element.

Answer (score 0):

Output both values on a single line, and let `read` separate the line into its two parts.

```
IFS=, read version patch < <($path_exec -version |
                             awk '/kernel release/ {v=$3}
                                  /patch number/ {p=$3}
                                  END {print v","p}
                                 ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I've managed to get it working thanks to your input:

```
version_patch_agent=$("${path_hostexec}" -version | awk '/kernel release/ {v=$3} /patch number/ {p=$3} END {print v" patch "p}')
```

This puts the version and patch number into a variable that I can just echo to get the info on the screen. Thanks again all!!